# Resolving dependencies in XAML using Autofac

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a class `MyResource` in my application that looks like this:

```
public class MyResource : IMyResource
{
    // ... whatever ...
}
```

And when I initialize my application in App.xaml.cs I have something like that using Autofac:

```
builder.Register<IMyResource>(container => new MyResource());
```

Now I need to add a `StaticResource` in a `Window` of my WPF application, something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyResource x:Key="MyResource" />
</Window.Resources>
```

But of course, the whole idea is *not to* reference a concrete instance of `MyResource` here. Moreover, I may need to use an instance of `MyResource` in different `Window`s or `UserControl`s across my application. So I would like to use an instance of `MyResource` as a `StaticResource` for my `Window` that is resolved through the Autofac container. How can I achieve this?

I was thinking of adding the resource in the code-behind of my `Window`, but it may create a dependency on my container which I don't want.

I was also thinking of doing something like that in App.xaml.cs, when I initialize the application:

```
App.Current.MainWindow.Resources.Add("MyResource", container.Resolve<IMyResource>());
```

But when I use the resource in my XAML

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=MyResource}}"/>
```

I get an `XAMLParseException` which inner exception's message stating that the resource named MyResource cannot be found. And even if it was working, I feel like it's a bit smelly.

So how can this be achieved? Is it only possible? If not what are the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps

- Register `MyWindow` and `MyResource` with Autofac.
- Place `IMyResource` in the constructor of `MyWindow` (Yes, you are modifying the code behind, but you are not referring to your container.  If you cannot have code in the Code-behind -- perhaps you are a UserControl --then make sure someone is setting the `DataContext` somewhere)
- Set `DataContext` to your concrete instance of `IMyResource` (in the constructor), or if you are using MVVM, place the instance into your viewmodel (which would also be registered with Autofac).
- Resolve `MyWindow`

In code:

```
MyWindow(IMyResource myResource) : this()
{
  DataContext = myResource;
}
```

If you are using a ViewModel (also registered with Autofac):

```
MyWindow(MyViewModel viewModel) : this()
{
  DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

Add this line to your XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext><local:IMyResource></Window.DataContext>
```

Or this:

```
<Window.DataContext><local:MyViewModel></Window.DataContext>
```

And then your markup for `ListBox` becomes trivial:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

Or, with the viewmodel, as the property `Items`, for instance, it's just as nice:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```